# Caching UITableView Images after load asynchronous

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, priority-queue

I load content in a UITableView from a WS and I tried to load the images asynchronous.
   Every time when I "move" the table the images are loading again.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCell";
    NewsCell *cell = ......

    NewsObject *obj = [self.dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.labelTitle.text   = obj.title;
    cell.textViewNews.text = obj.summary;

    cell.imgListIcon.image = nil;
    dispatch_queue_t imageQ = dispatch_queue_create("imageQ", NULL);
    dispatch_async(imageQ, ^{

        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.img]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imgListIcon.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [cell.spinner stopAnimating];
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(imageQ);

    return cell;
}
```

Can someone help me with some advice about this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Table view cells are reused every time they are shown/hidden. It allows not to create thousands of cells. So you need to store your loaded images. For example in dictionary with cell's index path as key and image as value. Then check if image for current cell is already loaded, just use it instead of loading again.